# prevent opening a link in new window right away. wait for user confirmation

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically generating a bunch of links in my web appliation (razor view).

Code:

```
foreach (var link in Model.Links)
{
     <a onClick="myFunc('@link.type', '@link.url')" target="_blank" href="@link.url"
     </a>
}


<script>
      function myFunc(type, url)
      {
          if (type = "Custom link")
          {
                 //Don't open the link yet
                 //Run a custom confirmation window
                 //Wait for user to respond to the dialog window
                 
                 //Sudo code

                 if (confirm=="YES")
                     //open link
                 else
                     // don't open link

          }
          else {
                 //open link
          }
      }
</script>
```

As can be seen in the comments - essentially what I am hoping to accomplish is:

1. For every link click, I want to call the JS function
2. If type = "Custom link" then don't open link until user confirms in the dialog
3. If other type then open link as normal

How can I implement the logic?

Comment: The simplest way to navigate is to set `document.location.href`. You could also use `window.open("new-url","_blank")` for opening in a new tab.

Comment: Alternatively, you could always use a query selector to grab the `a` element and send the `click()` event.

Comment: My set up currently works and opens the link in a new window. My problem is preventing the window from opening for custom links until the user confirms that they want to open in the dialog. Basically, the dialog opens in the current window, but the links open in a new window right away. It doesn't wait for user to confirm

Comment: type = "Custom link" is assignment. You need ===

Comment: You could always use a simple `confirm()` dialog. I would remove the `target="_blank" href="@link.url"` part of the `a` tag since you don't actually want to navigate on click, you want to call the `myFunc` function and then conditionally open a new window. I'd argue that you don't want the `a` tag at all. Traditionally, you would register an eventListener with the element and use `preventDefault()` to prevent navigation/submission.

Comment: just remove target="_blank"